# Clean ways to prime the kernel inode cache after boot?

Tags: linux, filesystems, performance, startup, cache

Various answers on various StackExchange sites cover parts of this topic, but I did not see an exact match for this scenario. How can you identify every mounted standard filesystem, and traverse all of the files and directories in order to warm up the kernel inode cache? Assuming these constraints:

- not interfering with normal booting
- not prolonging the normal boot process
- using only default or extremely popular utilities

I combined together my own expertise with ideas from other answers to create this one-liner, but I'm sure other shell golfers can improve on this, as it is not completely safe from various issues such as mount targets with unusual characters:

`findmnt --list --real --fstab --noheadings --output TARGET | egrep '^/' | xargs -P 0 -i bash -c 'find "{}" -xdev -type f,d,l -printf "" &>/dev/null &'`

This version performs the following steps, with some caveats noted:

1. Find all mounts in fstab, with real FS type; display without tree format or headings. This excludes virtual FSes which can misbehave during traversal or are in RAM and pointless to traverse.
2. **Note:** I could not find a clean way to skip over `none` target  fstab entries, such as swap partitions, without the egrep. One `findmnt` invocation cannot mix includes and excludes filters (unlike the more common `find` and `rsync` which can do this), and there is not a good way to split the filtering across multiple `findmnt` calls as far as I could see.
3. Execute an unlimited number of parallel `find` traversals for all directories, files, or symlinks in each mount target, without traversing other mount targets, with all possible output suppressed and ignored, in the background, to avoid a noisy console or a delayed boot. `xargs ... bash ...` is used for safety against some (but likely not all) unusual characters.
4. Place the command into `/etc/rc.local`. Even though recent `systemd` distributions do not have `rc.local` by default, `rc-local.service` will run it, if it is present and executable. This seems cleaner than using more config files and script files for such a trivial operation, but maybe there is a better way?

Comment: The kernel evicts inode cache with data cache, so not sure if this is really helpful.

Comment: Doesn't ureadahead do some of this already?